# Using liftIO and monad transformers, why is the type of a bound variable IO List instead of List?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm using EitherT in conjunction with IO for error handling. I have a function in the IO monad that gets data from a database so it has a type of IO [Value]. I use liftIO to lift this function into my EitherT IO monad and bind the result of this function to a variable. The problem is that GHC is telling me that the variable has the type IO [Value] instead of just [Value]. My code looks like this

```
    getItem :: (IConnection a) => a -> ItemId -> EitherT String IO Item
    getItem conn id = do
                    result <- liftIO $ do
                                        ... database stuf
```

It seems like i'm misunderstanding how liftIO and binding variables works. I thought that liftIO would take IO [Value] and return EitherT String IO [Value] and when bound to a variable, it would have the type [Value]. But it seems like I'm mistaken.

Comment: Seems like somewhere `Maybe` gets into the way. Could you check (in ghci for example) what's the type of the expression wrapped in `liftIO`? And perhaps post the whole function to see where from we're getting `Just`?

Comment: Aside, you might be interested in the concept that the [Ganeti](https://code.google.com/p/ganeti/) project (which I'm affiliated with) uses: A custom monad transformer named `ResultT`, isomorphic to `EitherT`, but whose [`liftIO` implementation](http://git.ganeti.org/?p=ganeti.git;a=blob;f=src/Ganeti/BasicTypes.hs;h=15a26a323a2d6091a032ee8410b9caddde91ac3f;hb=HEAD#l195) catches `IO` errors and converts them to the error part of the `ResultT` monad. This is very convenient as failing wrapped primitive `IO` operations are nicely handled by the monad.

Comment: What is the exact error that GHC gives you? Please post enough code (perhaps with implementations of irrelevant things stubbed out with `undefined`) that we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my issue. I was calling return on a value that was already an IO value, leading to IO (IO [Value]).

Comment: The last time I wrote a function that returned an `IO (IO [Value])` it was deliberate, but I've done it accidentally too.